# Web to App Interoperability - Any live example?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, android-intent

I read an interesting [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/web-to-app-interoperability-launch-your-android-app-from-the-web/1011) about Web-to-App interoperability. It states:

> Android and iOS allow installed applications to respond to custom URIs
>   from the web. Since I’m not as familiar with iOS, I will only cover
>   how Android allows this to work, and how you can use this technique to
>   your advantage. There are several use cases for allowing your app to
>   handle custom URIs. The first one I’ll cover is simply launching your
>   application.

Basically, a link (clicked on a mobile browser) can trigger a specific action with an installed App.

I found it intriguing and I realized that the Google Play Market itself works the same way with market:// links.

*My question is:*
**Can you provide (other) live examples in Android? And in Iphone?**

I'm looking for good cases of this kind of "Web to App Interoperability" with both Android and Iphone applications.

*Extra question:*
**Can you suggest a tutorial or reference to do this in Iphone?**

Thank you very much.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the extra question, have a look [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) or [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/).

I know Spotify uses this. I believe Facebook does too.